# circular image in table view cell swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, cornerradius

I am trying to create some a circular image in every row of my table view. I have followed tutorials but my image is turning out to be a diamond shape and not a circular one. What am I doing wrong:

```
 var cellImage = UIImage(named: pic)
 cell.imageView!.image = cellImage
 cell.imageView!.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 190, 190)
 cell.imageView!.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
 cell.imageView!.layer.masksToBounds = false
 cell.imageView!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

 cell.imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView!.layer.frame.height/2
 cell.imageView!.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Check the size of the imageView. You are using the imageView property of the cell. This is sized by the table view. If you added an image view to the cell, chose another name for it. Could you please show the code for the cell?

Comment: @dasdom thanks for your response. I am very new to swift so forgive my ingnorance. I think I am using the imageView property of the cell based of the code provided yes? Is the size not also illustrated in my code i.e. 190 by 190?

Comment: No, the size of the imageView of a table view cell is given by the size of the cell.

Comment: @dasdom also note the height of my table view rows are 200 (Set in storyboard source code)

Comment: @dasdom Ok I have printed out the size of my images (which will be coming from a webservice response). For now they are hardcoded and sitting in my imageassts folder. The first is optional 500.0 and the second is 200.0 Both are showing up as diamonds??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are creating your own imageView, it's better to set the cornerRadius inside the custom TableViewCell.

```
class CircularTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var circularImageView: UIImageView!
override func layoutSubviews() {
    circularImageView.layer.cornerRadius = circularImageView.bounds.height / 2
    circularImageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

}

Note the cornerRadius property can't guarantee that the view will be absolutely round unless you set the imageView's width and height ratio to be 1:1. Another approach to create round view is using Mask.

```
public extension UIView {
public func round() {
    let width = bounds.width < bounds.height ? bounds.width : bounds.height
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(bounds.midX - width / 2, bounds.midY - width / 2, width, width)).CGPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

}

This will allow you to call round() with any UIView and make sure the view is always round. e.g.

```
class CircularTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var circularImageView: UIImageView!
override func layoutSubviews() {
   circularImageView.round()
}
```

}

Comment: How do I create a custom table view cell, in the story board? Any tutorials on this or sample code? Note I am populating my table with a web service response and not all will have an image associated with them

Comment: I've upload a simple project which you can download and explore: https://github.com/vidaaudrey/CustomTableViewCell.  Basically you need to:   1. set up the prototype cell in storyboard, set the identifier and associate the cell with the corresponding class  2. create the custom UITableviewCell class  3. Config the cell at the UITableViewController to use the custom UITabelViewCell class.   If the certain cells are different, you can either use two kinds of UITableViewCell class or just further config custom UITableViewCell class (add or remove views, set different titles, etc...)

Comment: thanks for the sample project. Will have a look into and report back

Comment: When building I get the error could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell'  to 'projectname.CircularTableViewCell'. In your CircularTableViewCell.swift file, you have two outlets defined. So far to define outlets, I open the storyboard, click on the component of choice and open the assistant editor, drag and drop and choose outlet or action. When clicking on the table view in my storyboard and opening the assistant editor I am presented with my controller for the page with my table view and not the CircularTableViewCell.swift. How to get around this or would this be the issue?

Comment: I created a picture which can show you more details: [link](http://audreyli.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/cell-1.jpg)  In addition, to link the outlets, you can drag from storyboard, the structure view, or  the "connections inspector" (the right most tab).

Comment: This worked for me, as long as I called `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function after I set the ImageView image.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the static value(half of width or height) as corner radius.This may solve your problem.